# Can I have C as well as Java clients who can connect to same java server?

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I need to send message from multiple clients and those clients can be C clients or Java clients to server written in java.

Why I need to send over socket? Because there can be any process in any app on a same system who wants my app to capture there alarms and react accordingly.

Now, I can implement multiple Java clients who can connect to single Java server but how to do the same thing irrespective of it is Java client r C client.

If not socket programming, then what could be the other best way to make this communication happen

Comment: You could create a Java web application and expose a REST, SOAP, or other service which could be consumed by _any_ client with an internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

All low level network programming is written using sockets. you can have server written in any language communicate with client written in any language. To make this happen we have certain protocol which governs the communication like udp, tcp etc.
high level language provides api which will you to connect any server with single line of code without you needing to create socket. But in C you can create socket and connect it to the server. [see this](http://www.programminglogic.com/example-of-client-server-program-in-c-using-sockets-and-tcp/). All you need to know connect server and client is server ip and port...

Comment: Single client and single server is ok, but what I want is multiple clients (C, java etc.)who can connect to single server at the same time.

Comment: Yes. You can do it. The languages you choose are unimportant.

Comment: @Charu The whole point of communication protocols is that neither end has to be similar, just as long as they use the same protocol. It's all machine language no matter what language the source code is in.

Comment: @charu, the client has nothing to do with multiple communication. Your server is responsible for handling the multiple client. Implement server such that it can handle multiple client. Using threads you can achieve this easily. Dispatch a handler to every incoming request, let the threads handle client where your main program handles the incoming request and dispatching of thread to handle that request. When the request is handed over to the thread, the main can wait for another request.

Answer (score 0):

While your requirements are very broad it looks a lot like a prime candidate for protocol buffers.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Language agnostic.
Platform neutral.
Fast.

Running on ZeroMQ (http://zeromq.org/) where you can push and pretty much run on top of everything.